# how to eliminate .csv while reading and writing multiple files from folder

Tags: r

HI i have multiple file in one folder as a.csv,b.csv  ..... aaa.csv
i have written a code to import and write a data frames in R as below

```
folder <- "New folder/" 

file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")files in folder
```

## which shows a.csv,b.csv  ..... aaa.csv and if run the below code the output data frames created as same as filename like a.csv,b.csv...

How to remove .csv from datraframe while writing dataframes

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i], 
         read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep=''))
  )}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is something like `sub(".csv", "", file_list, fixed=TRUE)` what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Aksels we can do with your step and adding ".csv" in paste step like read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i],".csv",sep=''))